# Skip message in Kafka deserialization schema if any problems occur

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a simple `Apache Flink` job that ends with a `Kafka` sink. I'm using a `KafkaRecordSerializationSchema<CustomType>` to handle the message from the previous (`RichFlatMap`) operator:

```java
public final class CustomTypeSerializationSchema implements KafkaRecordSerializationSchema<CustomType> {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 5743933755381724692L;

  private final String topic;

  public CustomTypeSerializationSchema(final String topic) {
    this.topic = topic;
  }

  @Override
  public ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> serialize(final CustomType input, final KafkaSinkContext context,
      final Long timestamp) {
    final var result = new CustomMessage(input);
    try {
      return new ProducerRecord<>(topic,
          JacksonJsonMapper.writeValueAsString(result).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      logger.warn("Unable to serialize message [{}]. This was the reason:", result, e);
    }
    return new ProducerRecord<>(topic, new byte[0]);
  }
}
```

The problem I'm trying to avoid is to send an "empty" `ProducerRecord` — like the one that will be executed by default if something happens within the `try-catch`. Basically, I'm looking for a behavior similar to `KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema`, where what's put in the collector is what's going to be received in subsequent operators, and the rest is discarded.

Is there a way to achieve this with another `*SerializationSchema` type?